# Counting visible elements in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I want to know the number of **visible** elements shown after being subject to an *ng-if* and *ng-show*. Here is a simplified example:

```
$scope.fruits = [
        { name: 'apple', shape: 'round', color: 'red' },
        { name: 'stop sign', shape: 'pointy', color: 'red' },
        { name: 'orange', shape: 'round', color: 'orange' },
        { name: 'tomato', shape: 'round', color: 'red'}
    ];




    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" ng-if="fruit.color=='red'" ng-show="fruit.shape=='round'">{{fruit.name}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Is there a way to count the resulting number of items being shown?

Comment: you mean count of the result items??

Comment: Yes. Thanks for looking, but I was able to figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up not using the ng-if or ng-show at all, and just filtered the ng-repeat. This way, I did not have to hide anything and was easily able to get the length of the results.

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits | filter:myFilter | filter:{shape:'round'} as filteredFruits">{{fruit.name}}</li>
   {{filteredFruits.length}} fruits
</ul>

$scope.myFilter = function(x) {
    if (x.color == 'red') {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this you can remove your custom filter and use `as` keyword to get the `li` length.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.fruits = [
        { name: 'apple', shape: 'round', color: 'red' },
        { name: 'stop sign', shape: 'pointy', color: 'red' },
        { name: 'orange', shape: 'round', color: 'orange' },
        { name: 'tomato', shape: 'round', color: 'red'}
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">

<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits| filter:{'shape':'round', 'color':'red'}" >{{fruit.name}}</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits | notEmpty as Items" ng-if="fruit.color=='red'" ng-show="fruit.shape=='round'">{{fruit.name}}</li>
</ul>

<p>Number of Items: {{Items.length}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count number of items,

```js
$scope.fruits = [
            { name: 'apple', shape: 'round', color: 'red' },
            { name: 'stop sign', shape: 'pointy', color: 'red' },
            { name: 'orange', shape: 'round', color: 'orange' },
            { name: 'tomato', shape: 'round', color: 'red' }
        ];

        $scope.FindVisible = function () {
            var visibleObject=0;
            $scope.fruits.forEach(function (v, k) {                
                if (v.shape == 'round' && v.color == 'red') {
                    visibleObject = visibleObject + 1;                    
                }
            });
            alert(visibleObject);
        }
```

```html
<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" ng-if="fruit.color=='red'" ng-show="fruit.shape=='round'">{{fruit.name}}</li>
        <button ng-click="FindVisible()">Find</button>
</ul>
```